# Swapping two adjacent nodes in a linked list java

Tags: java, list, nodes

I have a very trivial problem, what should be a matter of just changing links. I've read a few answers, and some show how to do this by swapping the data, and some give a vague explanation of the concept.

Here's the method that seems to be running me in circles. When I swap the target node to the previous node, the node is simply skipped. Then when I go back to reference the next node, I get stuck in an eternal loop. I need to know If I need another node traversing from the head, or if I can simply reference the new link. I know I'm missing something quite obvious.

```
for (cursor = head; cursor != null; cursor = cursor.link) {
  if (target == cursor.data) {
    Target = cursor.link.getLink();
    next = cursor.getLink();
    prev = cursor;
    System.out.println(prev.getData()); // for testing
    System.out.println(next.getData());
    prev.setLink(Target); // Swaps the first link
    //Target.setLink(prev); // causes eternal loop
  }}
  return Target.getData();
}
```

This is my testing method, creating a list of 7 nodes, and printing to the screen.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SLL LL = new SLL(18, null);

  LL.add(4);
  LL.add(14);
  LL.add(8);
  LL.add(12);
  LL.add(2);
  LL.add(28);
  System.out.println(LL.toString());
  System.out.println(LL.swap(12));
  System.out.println(LL.toString());
}
```

This is the output I get:

> {18, 28, 2, 12, 8, 14, 4}
>
> 12
>
> 8
>
> 14
>
> {18, 28, 2, 12, 14, 4}

Desired output would be:

> {18, 28, 2, 12, 8, 14, 4}
>
> {18, 28, 2, 8, 12, 14, 4}

Comment: If possible post the code for `SLL` and `Target` classes. I see you use `cursor.link` sometimes and `cursor.getLink()` other times, so it's not clear about the specific behavior.

Comment: The constructor: public SLL(int initialData, SLL initialLink) { head = this; data = initialData; link = initialLink; }
All links shoould be .link, the .getLink() was just me messing around when it wasn't working. Everything is in one class

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to swap a specific node (determined by the value of the node) with the node after it?.

The easiest solution to the problem you presented is to just swap the values, instead of trying to swap the nodes.

Something like this should work since you're dealing with primitives

```
if(currNode.value() == targetValue) {
   Node nextNode = currentNode.next();
   currentNode.setValue(nextNode.getValue()); //set the current node's value to the next node's value
   nextNode.setValue(targetValue);
}
```

Just be sure to handle the case where your target value is in the last node in the list.

Edit- since for some reason you want to change the links instead, the general logic is-

- keep track of 3 nodes: prev, current, next
- set prev.link = next
- set current.link = next.link
- set next.link = current

Comment: Yes I am trying to swap the nodes based on the value of the node. My question is how to do this by changing only the links, rather than the values.

Comment: @Orch also a `break;` in the if statement is needed, otherwise the target value will be moved to the end of list

Comment: @Mattonio is this a homework question?  What is the reason you can't swap values?

Comment: @Orch even if it's not a homework question, that method is not great. What if the nodes are expanded to have more than one field? Then you have to change the `swap` method every time the `node` class changes, or gets extended.

Comment: @mypetlion My response is based on the question that was asked.  If you change the question, then the response would probably change  as well, that seems obvious.

Comment: This is an exercise from the textbook "open data structures" The object is to compare the efficiency between swapping in singly and doubly linked lists.

Comment: Well this should answer your question.  Right now the way you're setting links is incorrect.